# Facebook Hotel Chatbot to ask Stay Duration

Tags: facebook, chatbot

So I've developed my hotel chatbot to answer to a postback with "When would you like to check in?" I suppose the next step would be to check if the user's answer is a valid date, or else prompt the question again.  Is there a way to save this state of  "we're now asking for the duration" so that the chatbot knows to ask for the duration again if the user types gibberish?  Since outside of the stay duration question my chatbot just prompts the general menu when users type anything random.

For example when Domino's Pizza is asking for my street address, it asks again if I type something invalid, as opposed to giving me the general menu again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, `Entities` or `Slots` are used for this purpose.

Complete Event data (event data contains data related to queries, intents, entities, sessions, user etc) is passed between user and chatbot every time and we check if all the entities are filled or not one by one.

If any entity which is required is not yet fulfilled, then we prompt to user with relevant question (stay duration in your case).
Once all the entities are filled, and we are ready to perform the action we complete the action and reply to user with the result.

Hope it helps.